# OracleRightNow health check endpoint

Tags: wsdl, rightnow-crm

We have an application that depends on ORN.

We want to have a health check endpoint for that application to know if it works fine and all its dependencies work fine.

In order to check if ORN is working, currently we are using:

```
https://support.something.com/cgi-bin/something.cfg/services/soap?wsdl
```

as health check endpoint for ORN. It works fine, but it's too big (1800 lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Copyright @ 2009, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    http://www.oracle.com
-->

<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"

...

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Is there another **health check endpoint for ORN**?

Ideally, I'd like something to have something like this:

```
https://support.something.com/cgi-bin/something.cfg/check
```

that returns just

```
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to test the availability of the SOAP API, all APIs, the Customer Portal, or something else.  Depending on your test, the answer will be different.  APIs might be up while CP is down, or any potential combination of the distributed components of the platform.

For the SOAP API test that you have, rather than checking for WSDL availability, you could try one of the SOAP operations that returns fewer lines; a ROQL query would probably be a good choice.

The REST API would probably be the root "connect" path, which doesn't require authentication.  `https://my.osvc.site.com/services/rest/latest`.

For Customer Portal, you could just hit the index/home page, which would tell you that CP is up.

Chat could use a REST/SOAP approach as mentioned above.

Email probably cannot be checked in any useful way in this manner.

Of course, you could implement a CP controller or custom script that acts as an API endpoint, but that is not a best practice and will probably not be a good longterm solution, even though such practices are commonplace in the SI space currently.